# How do i run this "run_scaled" script from github

Tags: bash

I want to start using Linux, but I am having problem with scaling in my HiDPI display.

I found this code called "run_scaled" on github, which everyone recommends for my issue, allowing me to scale 2x individual applications.

The problem is that I am unable to run the script and get run_scaled to be recognized as command.

I tried going to the directory and using

`~$ sh run_scaled`

but it only outputs something that is like the README.md

```
Usage: run_scaled [--scale=scaling_factor] [--opengl=auto|yes|no] [--sleep=sleeptime] application

--scale  Sets the factor the application is scaled by. Fractional scales are
         supported. It is set to 2 by default.
--opengl Sets whether xpra should use opengl for rendering. If you get rendering
         errors, especially when the window is resized, try setting it to no. It
         is set to auto by default.
--sleep  Sets how many seconds to wait after starting xpra before attaching to
         the xpra session. It is set to 1 by default.
         You might need to increase the value if your machine is particularly
         slow and attaching fails with a message like

             InitException: cannot find any live servers to connect to
             xpra initialization error:
              cannot find any live servers to connect to
```

Comment: Here is the code i am trying to use

https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled

Comment: As you pointed out, it's a README, and if you read it, it's actually explaining to you how to use the script ("**Usage**"). It's telling you what parameters to pass to the script for it to work.

Comment: When I try to use it as stated in the README it doesn't recognize run_scaled as a command.

Comment: You have to have the executable in your `$PATH`. I recommend cloning the GitHub repository to the directory `/usr/local/run_scaled` and adding a symlink `/usr/local/bin/run_scaled` → `/usr/local/run_scaled/run_scaled`. WFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make the script executable:

```
$ cd /path/to/dir/with/run_scaled
$ sudo chmod +x run_scaled
```

Then run it:

```
$ ./run_scaled application
```

The "./" at the start means "from this directory, call the file called run_scaled". You can also run it with `bash` (as indicated by the shebang at the top of the script)

```
$ bash run_scaled application
```

As indicated in the README and help/usage, you can also pass options:

```
$ ./run_scaled --scale=2 application
```

You need to be in the directory where the script is (that's probably why you're getting the unrecognized command error, you're in the wrong directory). If you want to run the script from anywhere, you need to add the script's dir to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The usage is:

```
run_scaled [...] application
```

You need to provide an application for it to run. For example:

```
run_scaled firefox
run_scaled --scale=2 gedit
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't recognize "run_scaled" as a command. :/